# where to put .tld file while using spring boot and configged with completely java code

Tags: jsp, spring-boot, taglib

In the old way, we put custom taglib description file at WEB-INF/xxx.tld, and JSP files load this file with `<%@taglib prefix="xxx" uri="/META-INF/xxx.tld"%>`

When we use Spring boot and config the application completely with java code (no web.xml, xxx-servlet.xml etc.), where to put it?

under resources/WEB-INF? or resources/META-INF?

Comment: which container are you using? How are you packaging your app (war? jar?)

Comment: @BrianClozel I'm going to use Tomcat and package the app to war

Answer (score 2):

Just drop your tld in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ and reference it from your jsp using the uri.

Example of tld located in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <description>Example Tag Library</description>
    <tlib-version>4.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>example</short-name>
    <uri>http://www.example.org/tags</uri>

    <tag>
       <name>exampleTag</name>
       <tag-class>com.example.taglib.ExampleTag</tag-class>
       <body-content>empty</body-content>
    </tag>
</taglib>
```

Example of referencing your tag library from a JSP file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="ex" uri="http://www.example.org/tags"%>
```

And of course, using your custom tags:

```
<ex:exampleTag />
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're aware of the various [JSP limitations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations), Spring Boot is sticking as much as possible to the "old way".

In that particular case, I don't think Spring Boot is involved at all in loading custom TLDs, but rather the container's job. Feel free to put it where it should be in regular WAR applications and raise an issue to the Spring Boot team with a repro project in case this doesn't work.

Comment: I found the war package would generate a "WEB-INF" folder anyway, so I put "xxx.tld" under resources folder, and change the taglib announcement to <%@taglib prefix="xxx" uri="/WEB-INF/classes/xxx.tld"%> , there is no compile error in STS (haven't tested if it works well after running), not sure if this is a right way